# Strapi & Next.JS - SEO data at build time

Tags: next.js, seo, strapi

I've had a crack at trying to get a dynamic SEO component working for my website, by grabbing the data, waiting until it's loaded, and inserting it into a component. I'm going to change some of the names of things to simplify the example.
This is in one of my pages, an [id].js that Next supports.

```js
import Head from "next/head"
import {useRouter} from 'next/router'
import Layout from "../../components/layout/layout"
import SEO from "../../components/layout/seo"
import { DATA } from "../../components/dataFetch"

const ID = () => {
    const router = useRouter()
    const { id } = router.query

    const strapi = DATA(`strapi?_slug=${id}`)
    // ...
    return (
      <Head>
        {!strapi.loading && strapi.data.map((s) => {
          <SEO

            title={s.name} // the name of the strapi item
            description={strapi.description} // description for whatever it is
            keywords={[s.name, s.keyword_tag, s.keyword_tag_2]} // mostly an example
            image={s.thumb.formats.medium.url} // image

          />
        })}
      </Head>
    )
}
```

And then here is what the SEO component in question looks like:

```js
import React from 'react'

const SEO = ({title, description, keywords, image}) => {
    if (keywords) { /* combine all the keywords in the array and make it a string for meta */
        keywords.join(',')
    }
    if (!image) { /* Set the default image if there is none currently */
        image = 'https://google.com/image.png';
    }
    return (
        <>
            {/* meta */}
            <title>{title} | website</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width"/>
            <meta name="description" content={description} />
            <meta name="keywords" content={keywords} />
            {/* og */}
            <meta property="og:title" content={`${title} | website`} key="facebook title" />
            <meta property="og:description" content={description} />
            <meta property="og:url" content="" />
            <meta property="og:image" content={image} />
            {/* twitter */}
            <meta property="twitter:title" content={`${title} | website`} key="twitter title" />
            <meta property="twitter:description" content={description} />
            <meta property="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
            <meta property="twitter:image" content={image} />
        </>
    )
}

export default SEO
```

This SEO code will work in a place like the index page, because the data isn't fetched - it's statically written (at least in the home page). I want to try and get it so that I can dynamically grab this content and insert it into my header if possible.

And as well, just to make sure all of my bases are covered, here is my dataFetch component, which is referenced as `` DATA(`strapi?_slug=${id}`) `` in the code.

```js
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

export const DATA = (query) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([])
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
    const [error, setError] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async() =>
        {
            setError(false)
            setLoading(true)
            try {
                const res = await axios(`${process.env.REACT_APP_STRAPI_API}/${query}`)
                setData(res.data)
            } catch (error) {
                setError(true)
            }
            setLoading(false)
            console.log(data, query)
        }
        fetchData()
    }, [query])

    return {data, loading}
}
```

This dataFetch code works fine in the context of fetching the data and providing it. For just about all the strapi data I grab. Not sure this would be a problem but just wanted to include it, just in case.

So TD;LR: Trying to dynamically generate SEO meta headers with Strapi Data, isn't working as the connection isn't working at lightspeed so it appears as an error 500 and doesn't append the data to the header. Any tips?

Comment: hi , if you want dynamic data , you most to use getStaticProps or getServerSideProps , because when your website cruled,  The first data for SEO must be ready

Comment: As @H9ee pointed out, if you want the metadata on the server response you need to make the API call on the server-side instead.